# Multiple View Controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

Using Xcode 9.1 Cocoa Swift, I'm trying to create a login screen so once the user puts in the requirements and pushes the button a new screen will appear within the application. Right now I'm just trying to get the program working with the button in place. My issue is when the button is pressed, a new window opens and the login window has not terminated.

[image]

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewConroller

@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
    func dismissViewController(_ viewController: NSViewController)
```

Comment: I'm by no means an OSX dev, but in iOS the answer would be that when doing a segue (usually push segue) to another view controller, you're adding that view controller to your nav stack.  The login view controller is your root view controller and will never be deleted.  I'd expect the same behavior on Cocoa but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Well what would you use in iOS to do this sort of thing?

Comment: If you want the login window to be destroyable, put a view controller before it. Make that view controller your app’s initial view controller, which just immediately segues to tour login VC.  Then when login VC completes login, unwind back to the first VC before then segueing wherever you want to go next.